# Flowchart of objects created in a R script

Tags: r

I want to track all R objects created in a big script.

For the dummy script below

```
dataA=data.frame(col1=1:10)
dataA$col2=dataA$col1*2
dataA$col3=dataA$col1*3
```

a single dataframe object gets modified by adding new columns in two separate steps.  Thus, a flow chart rough model would be

```
(dataframe)dataA(10x1) -> dataA(10x2) -> dataA(10x3)
```

I have multiple objects in the script.  Is there any R package
that automatically create a flow chart from all the objects created?

I found one package track (http://cran.nexr.com/web/packages/track/vignettes/track.pdf).  But, it is archived and its summary output is not easily understandable.